# Symfony loading assets from template

Tags: css, symfony, assets

I cant link my style in Symfony.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/styles/css/global.min.css') }}" />`

My CSS file is in assets dir

- yes i have allready downloaded asset from symfony
- yes i have tried change directories

Comment: Do you see any errors at all?

Comment: clear cache   (delete folder var/cache/*   or php bin/console c:c -e prod)

Comment: If you don't use symfony encore for managing your assets, store them in your public dir. And call your assets with : `{{ asset('styles/css/global.min.css') }}` (where your styles dir is in public)

Answer (score 1):

In SF3, you should store your assets in

```
Store your assets in the web/ directory.
```

https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/best_practices/web-assets.html

In SF4, you should store your assets in

```
Store your assets in the assets/ directory at the root of your project.
```

and use Webpack Encore to compile, combine and minimize web assets.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/web-assets.html

This is my configuration (SF3): 
`config_dev.yml`

```
framework:
# Assets CDN & dev paths
# change here and in the config_prod.xml
assets:
    packages:
        avatar:
            base_path: upload/members/pics/
        app_css:
            base_path: css/
        app_img:
            base_path: img/
        ....
```

`config_prod.yml - if you want to use CDN`

```
framework:
# Assets CDN & dev paths
# change here and in the config_prod.xml
assets:
    packages:
        avatar:
            base_path: xx.xx.xx.xx/upload/members/pics/ (IP Address of CDN)
        app_css:
            base_path: xx.xx.xx.xx/css/(IP Address of CDN)
        app_img:
            base_path: xx.xx.xx.xx/img/ (IP Address of CDN)
        ....
```

In twig :

```
    <a href="{{ path('homepage') }}" class="logo" style="background-image:url({{ asset('logo.svg', 'app_img') }})"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your assets must be in the Asset folder before compiling them. The compiled version should be in the web folder (SF 3 without flex) or in the public folder (sf4 with flex)